# Domain specific routes - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Im building my first big/complex nodejs (express) app. Whats special about it is that I want to serve the app on different domains. But depending on the domain it should show slightly different content and styling. Say I have these three domains:

carapp.com

truckapp.com

bikeapp.com

I use nginx as a reverse proxy and it serves the static files. Now I need help to figure out the best way to add unique routes to each domain. I have considered adding a middleware sort of like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   if(req.headers.host === 'carapp.com'){
      app.use(indexRoutes1);
   }
   if(req.headers.host === 'truckapp.com'){
      app.use(indexRoutes2);
   }
   if(req.headers.host === 'bikeapp.com'){
      app.use(indexRoutes3);
   }
   next();
});
```

But I can't figure out if it is the right way to go about it. Hope someone can give me some good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is exactly what i would suggest. Using the host header matches the intended purpose of the `Host` header: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23

You might consider to default to one of the three pages in case the `Host` header is missing or doesn't match one of the three pages, e.g. if someone uses the IP to connect.